# Upload very long text to a web form

Tags: .net, http, upload, http-post

I have a web form and I want to submit very long texts (say 32k) to the form, I tried code below but receive server errors, while short texts have no problem, server is IIS serving PHP. Shall I use form submission instead of posting parameters, if yes then how? :)

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Proxy = null;

    var uval = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
               {
                   { "msg", very_long_string_base64_encoded },
                   { "type", "report" }
               };
    try
    {
        var response = client.UploadValues(new Uri("http://www.domain.com/upload.php"), uval);
        string result_in_text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        e.Result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        e.Result = false;
    }
}
```